# How are Euler's laws of motion applied to gyroscopes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes

Euler's laws of motion for a distributed mass are:

$$F = \frac{d}{dt} MV_{cm},\ N = \frac{d}{dt} L$$

$F$ are the sum of the external forces, $M$ the total mass, $V_{cm}$ the velocity of the centre of mass.  $N$ are the sum of the moments of the external forces about some given point, L the total angular momentum about the same point.

If a gyroscope is supported at its base with its axis horizontal, it precesses at a constant angular velocity. Using the above equations, how does one show this?

Answer (score 1):

Start off ignoring gravity.  The spin axis is horizontal?  Well then, you have an L vector.  Very simple, nothing happens.

Now turn on gravity.  This pulls down on the centre of mass, which is elsewhere from the pivot.  That gives you an N vector - cross product of force with location relative to the pivot.  This is perpendicular to the axis - so perpendicular to L.   This is the change in L, according to N=dL/dt.   In an arbitrarily small change in time, dt, we find dL will not change the length of L but will change its directions.  Repeat indefinitely for every dt in a finite time interval t_1 to t_2.

Comment: +1 This answer is close to what I'm looking for, but you haven't said anything about Euler's first equation for the motion of the centre of mass in a circle.

Answer (score 0):

You have to expand out $L=I\,\omega$ and notice how both terms vary with time. In many books they expand upon this to come to the equation of $\rm{d}L/\rm{d}t = I\,\dot{\omega} + \omega\times I\,\omega$

So there is a solution with $\omega>0$ and $\dot\omega=0$ for a constant $N$.

PS. Is this related to a homework problem?

**EDIT:**
Do a [Free Body Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_body_diagram) to balance gravity with the reaction force to notice there is a net moment of the center of gravity $N>0$. So the above has a stead state solution of $N=\omega\times I\,\omega$ (with $\dot\omega=0$, $L=I\,\omega$). If the angular momentum $L$ is not aligned with the rotation axis $\omega$ then there exists a non-zero vector $\omega>0$ to satisfy the above equation.

**Example:**
if $\vec\omega = [\cos\varphi\,\dot\theta,\sin\varphi\,\dot\theta,\Omega]$ where $\Omega$ is the precession speed, $\varphi$ the orientation/precession angle and $\dot\theta$ the spin rate, then the angular momentum in an axis alinged with the object but not spining is $L_\rm{body}=[I_{xx}\,\dot\theta,0,\Omega\,(I_{zz}+m\,L^2)]$. Then

$$ N = [\dot\theta,0,\Omega] \times [I_{xx}\,\dot\theta,0,\Omega\,(I_{zz}+m\,L^2)] = [0,\Omega\dot\theta (I_{xx}-I_{zz}-m\,L^2),0]$$

all expressed in this intermediate coordinate frame. So a torque component about the $y$-axis supports the gyroscope precession.

Comment: it's not homework and I appreciate your answer, but it didn't answer my question using Euler's laws of motion that I stated at the beginning.